# \copy in is unable to fit utf-8 into varying(30)

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

In order to build the staging database from my production data to test migrations, etc. I do a regular `\copy` of a subset of production records to CSV files, and import the result.  I do this for the specific tables with are very large (600G), as I don't need them all for testing.
One such column is a varying(30) [for hysterical raisins involving django 1].

I have data in that column which is UTF-8 encoded. Some of it is exactly 30 glyphs wide. But, that takes more than 30 bytes to encode. Strangely, it fits just fine in the original database, but after creating a new database, it does not fit.

I copy in with:

```
\copy public.cdrviewer_cdr from '/sg1/backups/2017-02-20/cdr.csv'
```

with (format 'csv', header, encoding 'utf-8') ;

This seems like it may be a bug, or maybe it's just a limitation of copy.

(I am using postgresql 9.6 on Devuan Jessie)

Comment: Post one line of the csv which shows the problem.

Comment: Please show output of `\l` in `psql`. At a guess your new database is not using UTF-8 encoding, but something else. `COPY` is used by postgres for dump and restore, so I'm pretty sure problems with character counts and length limits would cause loud wailing rather rapidly.